# Updating already existing json file python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file and I want to update 'filename' field with the filenames I scp from a remote server. I am pretty new to python but learning as I go.

JSON file:

```
{"path":"/home/Document/Python", 
"md5s":[{"filename":"",
    "md5":"",
    "timestamp":""},
   {"filename":"",
    "md5":"",
    "timestamp":""},
   {"filename":"",
    "md5":"",
    "timestamp":""}
]}
```

My python code so far:

```
  def filemd5():
   try:
    config = json.load(open(config_file))
    #print(str(json.dumps(config, indent=4)))
    for server in config['servers']:
            ssh = SSHClient() 
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()

            ssh.connect(server['ip'], username=server['username'], 
                        password=server['password'])
        #print(str(server)) 
        print('Connecting to servers')
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp/')
        error = str(ssh_stderr.read())
        if len(error) ==0:
            for files in config['servers']: 
                filename = file_location + server['file']
                scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
                scp.get(filename)
            if os.path.isfile(server['file']):
                updateJsonFile(filename)
                print(filename)
            else:
                print('KO')

def updateJsonFile(filename):
        with open('md5.json', 'r') as f:
           data = json.load(f)

       subdata = data['md5s']
       for check in subdata:
           check["filename"] = filename

       with open('md5.json', 'w') as f:
           f.write(json.dumps(data))

filemd5()
```

Formatting has not really came out well here but I am nearly sure it is good in my python script. 
What is happening now is that it populates all fields 'filename' with the same file when I am SCP three files from different servers.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

EDIT(updated question as adding to file works but it fills all values with same filename.

Expected result:

```
{"path":"/home/Document/Python", 
 "md5s":[{"filename":"text1.txt",
"md5":"",
"timestamp":""},
{"filename":"text2.txt",
"md5":"",
"timestamp":""},
{"filename":"text3.txt",
"md5":"",
"timestamp":""}
 ]}
```

Actual:

```
 {"path":"/home/Document/Python", 
 "md5s":[{"filename":"text1.txt",
"md5":"",
"timestamp":""},
{"filename":"text1.txt",
"md5":"",
"timestamp":""},
{"filename":"text1.txt",
"md5":"",
"timestamp":""}
 ]}}
```

Comment: `filename` is contained in a list. To access it, you would need something like `subdata = data['md5s']` to get the list, then iterate through `subdata` to change specific `filename` values. But it's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do so I can't be more specific than that

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding quickly. I edited my post for a desired output and what im actually getting

Comment: That's definitely your actual output? That's not valid json so this is confusing! But in your expected output, what has caused `text2.txt` to appear at index `1`? As I said, you need to first obtain the list object through `data['md5s]` then you need some counter to know which dictionary object within that file you want to change the value of `filename` to.

Comment: I did what you said and it works, I can add the filename to the json but now it will print the same filename for all three. Is there a way to tell json to go to the next 'filename' and populate that with the next file that I SCP?

Comment: Basically, pass an index to your function e.g. `def updateJsonFile(filename, index):`. Get the `subdata` then something like `subdata[index]['filename'] = filename`. Index indicates which of the `filename` values you want to update

Comment: So I do I set the 'index=0' for the first one and so on? Im not sure how to add 'index' to my def filemd5() method..

Comment: I'm not sure either since it's up to you how you want to populate the json and I think something is wonky in `for files in config['servers']: ` since the `if` is outside of the scope of the `for` loop. But, I would imagine you want your counter within that loop, and increment the counter every time `if os.path.isfile(server['file']):` is `True`, or you increment it in the outer `for server in config['servers']:` loop if indeed your indentation is how you need it to be

Comment: I added what you said and I get 'Key error: 0' ?

Comment: At this point you'll need to update the code block in your question sorry

Comment: I did. Please see the update

Comment: This is python.  It is not sufficient to say "formatting has not come out well here".  Formatting changes the meaning of the code.    You simply have to get it right in the question, otherwise we are debugging something different than you're running.

Comment: I understand @GreenAsJade but I tried to space it out correctly from my script file. I just wanted to point out that to everyone. My loops are the way I want them but there is the odd space here or there that doesn't make a difference to the code but looks sloppy. (the first 'with' is not in line with 'subdata'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as I can come to sorting the code for you. I don't know why you get `KeyError` but you didn't implement a counter as suggested in the comments. Since I don't have access to `config['servers']`, the counter might be in the wrong place, in which case put it in the inner `for` loop. I tested this on your json string and it does work as you intended so the principle is correct, you just have to make sure you pass the desired values for `counter`.

```
def filemd5():
    try:
        config = json.load(open(config_file))

        counter = 0 # Add a counter here
        for server in config['servers']:
            ssh = SSHClient() 
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()

            ssh.connect(server['ip'], username=server['username'], 
                            password=server['password'])

            print('Connecting to servers')
            ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp/')
            error = str(ssh_stderr.read())
            if not error: 
                for files in config['servers']: 
                    filename = file_location + server['file']
                    scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
                    scp.get(filename)
                if os.path.isfile(server['file']):
                    updateJsonFile(filename, counter)
                    counter += 1 # increment the counter
                    print(filename)
                else:
                    print('KO')
    except:
        # I don't understand why you don't get an error for missing except?
        pass  

def updateJsonFile(filename, counter):
    with open('md5.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    subdata = data['md5s']
    # The code below would update every value since you loop through whole list
    #for check in subdata:
    #   check["filename"] = filename
    subdata[counter]['filename'] = filename

    with open('md5.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Man thank you sooooo much!! I am relatively new to python and just needed that slight bit of help  to get this working and you've saved me a huge headache. I really appreciate all you help.. Desired output is now working. All files added and accounted for.

Comment: @Relentless You're welcome :) As a note, the `else` you observed in the answer by Serge is a good addition to this. My code demonstrates how you would modify yours to get at the correct json object, but adding an `if/else` or even `try/except` to extend the json is a lot more fault-tolerant (my approach would probably throw an index error instead if you tried to add a 4th item for example)

Comment: Yeah I really liked the if else because it will avoid some exceptions that could cause me further problems.  I will test now just to see but it is something I will surely need down the line. I do appreciate your help. I need to read some more documentation I think.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood, you start with a json file containing a list of references to file, and you want to update the next element of the list.

You could browse the `data['md5s']` searching for the first element where the  `filename` field is empty, and add a new dictionnary to the list if all are already completed:

```
def updateJsonFile(filename):
    jsonFile = open("md5.json", "r")  # load data from disk
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()

    for tmp in data["md5s"]:  # browse the list
        if len(tmp['filename']) == 0:  # found one empty slot, use it and exit looop
            tmp['filename'] = filename
            break
    else:     # no empty slot found: add a new dict
        data["md5s"].append({'md5': '', 'timestamp': '', 'filename': filename})
    jsonFile = open("m.json", "w")  # write the json back to file
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()
```

Comment: I maybe didn't explain it great, but the else in the code above is something im going to implement now as it would be a great addition to what I have to do. I appreciate you taking the time to help.